# What should design of our icon be?

Tags: discussion, design

Current icon is quite meaningless:

[image]

Even some beta sites (such as https://aviation.stackexchange.com/, https://chess.stackexchange.com/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/) have beautiful icons, maybe we should already care about icon design?

Note that also this icon should be meaningfull at 16x16 size (favicon).

Comment: Perhaps a heart shape to represent "life"?

Comment: I'd say we get this into public beta first and then worry about graduation....

Comment: It's too early to focus on design issues

Comment: @Inf On emacs.se, [it wasn't too early](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/133/is-the-current-favicon-the-best-we-can-do), so I decided to bring it up there also.

Comment: *Most* beta sites have simple initials in their favicon unless there's a reason to give them something else. Otherwise sites get a custom favicon as part of their graduation design, if they ever get that far.

Comment: IDK about the downvotes, but I think this is a important question and will become even more important if there is a future to this site.

Comment: @ili As you see, it was 3/5 before you up voted, so someone considers this question to be important anyway :)

Comment: Well actually it is 4/5, but someone doesn't think it is important :/

Comment: @ili I said "it was 3/5 *before you upvoted*" ;)

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have any idea about guideline for Stack Exchange iconography (e.g. margin/padding, optical square), so this would be more-or-less just a rough idea. And so, I propose...

[image: lifehacks icon proposal]

Probably, the most literal icon that I could think of: life (heart) + hacks (to fix). Maybe it also conveys "unconventional way" since I can't imagine using wrench to fix heart.

The standard favicon asset that SE uses (32x32) will look like

[image: favicon 32]

although, I find it a bit difficult to understand for common favicons (16x16)

[image]

Comment: This icon is just... *gorgeous*. And very clever.

Comment: 1+ for the awesome design, but the maybe the heart should be changed to something else that symbolizes life, maybe a Planet Earth model or something. But this could be taken to mean that it is some kind of health site, but if it can't be changed I think it is fine as it is.